# Reading structured data in VB.NET from MFC DLL function using P/Invoke

Tags: c++, xml, vb.net, mfc

I have the following structure in an MFC DLL:

```
struct retornoSAP
{
    enum tipoRetorno
    {
        Ok,
        Falha,
        AbrirArquivo, // mStrData válido
        InserirArquivo, // mStrData válido
        retornoMap, // mLstData válido
        retornoTable, // mLstTable válido
        retornoString, // mStrData válido
    };

    tipoRetorno mTipo;
    CString mStrData;
    CMapStringToString mLstData;
    retTable* mLstTable;
    CMapStringToString mLstVars;

    retornoSAP( tipoRetorno pTipo )
    {
        mTipo = pTipo;
        mLstTable = NULL;
    }
    ~retornoSAP()
    {
        if ( mLstTable  ) CISap::release( mLstTable  );
    }
};
```

retTable definition is:

```
typedef vector<CMapStringToString*> retTable;
```

This structure is used to store data read from an SAP API, and I have a lot of functions that return a "retornoSAP" value.

It happens that I have to call those functions from VB.NET, using P/Invoke (DllImport). I have read some material about marshaling unmanaged types to .NET (like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/02/18/marshalling-complicated-structures-using-pinvoke.aspx), and it probably would be easy to marshal a structure with some basic types in it, but I wonder if it is even possible to marshal a CMapStringToString or, even worse, a vector of CMapStringToString.

My question is if it's worth spending some time trying to translate this structure to a .NET type (in this case, where I could find some good documentation)?

If not, I wonder if it sounds like a good idea to use a XML parser in C++, write all my data to a XML structure, and then return that XML structure as a BSTR string, so I could read the BSTR return value easily it in my .NET application and parse it back to a XML structure. In that case, I would pass some big strings between the MFC DLL and the .NET application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really deal with MFC classes with P/INVOKE. I think you can choose one of two option:

1. Not touching the MFC dll at all: create a dll with [CLI C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx). Some effort to learn the language, but is a thunk dll, you don't need to study it all. This way you can expose some `ref classes` to `.NET` world and call from its methods the MFC dll. From inside the ref class you can read your original MFC structures and populate some other structures more .NET friendly.
2. Modify the MFC dll, expose some entry point with `extern "C"` decoration, in order to avoid name mangling, and convert internal structure in something easyer to manage, string as you guess, would be a not so elegant, but cutting edge solution;)

Both solution have some performance overhead, but I guess the first one would pay better, and it is sometimes the only one preventing modification to the original MFC dll, and sometimes this is desiderable. Second one is probably simpler, but passing magic string would involve some parsing leading to performance leak, possible errors so you need more test, more costs and so on.

Another drawback of solution 1 is you need an extra deploy for the C++/CLI redistributables.

I did not mention since you probably already know, but doing this kind of interop needs the .NET code compiled in x86 mode if your target C++ dll are 32 bit compiled.